# Strange, Possibly Idiomatic Sentence and the Adverb лишь

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление, значения, idioms

What is the meaning of the following sentence:

> будь жена хоть коза, лишь бы золотые рога

I understand all the words in the sentence, and I've roughly translated it as: "Whether a wife be a she-goat, if only the golden horn" This is a confusing and unsatisfying translation.The meaning of this sentence does not seem to be compositional, so I've come here seeking aid from a native speaker to whom this sentence is perhaps familiar.

More generally, I have a question about the use of **лишь**. I've read [some places](http://www.italki.com/question/205996) that **лишь** is not often used colloquially and is seen mostly in song lyrics. I've only seen it before in the song "В траве сидел кузнечик" in the line *он съел одну лишь травку*. Yandex translates лишь as 'only,' 'just,' or 'merely.' If this is so, is лишь merely synonymous with **только**, or does it have a different, more specific, usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is translated something like "You can have even a goat wife in case she has golden horns".  It's not an "if" per se, it is sort of "in case one don't find him or herself in this situation".

`Лишь` is a pretty tricky word indeed. There are some subtly different meanings:

- only, merely, just: `Я горжусь лишь тем, чего достиг сам`. So it is indeed to some extent synonymous to "только" but be warned, there also:
- лишь только: as soon as. `Лишь только наступил вечер, она уже уснула.`
- лишь бы: only if.

The last one is exactly your case. 
As of how often is is used - well, I'd say it's usage is gradually declining but it would be too radical to consider is obsolete.

Comment: человек спросил значение пословицы, а не дословный перевод. Вы что, выражение, например, "шило в мешке не утаишь" воспринимаете буквально?

Comment: @user907860 автор спросил про значения слова лишь в данном контексте, а потом задал ещё несколько релевантных вопросов про это же самое слово. Но спасибо! Я сейчас добавлю пояснение - про рога действительно может быть непонятно. 

Но вопрос не столько значение пословицы, сколько про слово лишь.

Comment: автор спросил **What is the meaning of the following sentence**, это не *про значения слова лишь в данном контексте*

Comment: @user907860 я предлагаю вам воспользоваться этим случаем и оставить свой ответ ;)

Comment: я не могу объянить полностью разницу между "только" и "лишь", а то несомненно бы написал

Answer (score 6):

*Лишь бы* here means *as long as*.

The phrase means *Don't care if the wife is a goat as long as she has golden horns*.

Comment: So the idiomatic meaning could be something like: "don't consider the looks of your wife, but rather how wealthy she is" ?

Comment: @студент001: right (except that it's sarcasm, it's usually said about a male gold digger)

Comment: it does not mean **Don't care if the wife is a goat as long as she has golden horns.** It means "I don't care who the wife is, if she is ugly, so long, as she provides enough money/wealth etc."

Comment: @Quassnoi can you imagine since today I was like 100% sure that it is "лишь бы у мужа не золотые рога" - always something new to learn ))

Comment: @user907860: do you think that "goat with golden horns" in bridal context is that untranslatable?

Comment: basically I think that there is a big difference between a translation and a meaning. Especially with proverbs.

Comment: @user907860: I was answering under impression that the phrase *будь жена ходь уродина, лишь бы много денег в кошельке* would have been equally misunderstood by the op. In other words, it was not the goat and golden horns, but *будь* and *лишь бы* the op was really asking about.